# Homework Help - Reading code and counting integers

Tags: excel, vba, integer

I need some assistance trying to grasp a concept that our teacher is trying to get across. This is a beginning VBA Access course and we have just coded our first simple project. Unfortunately, I am unsure if I am not grasping the concept because he's not explaining clearly or if he's doing a poor job explaining. I am asking someone watch this 4 min video and see if they can understand it, and if so to maybe take a sample code and explain it a little further.

http://www.ciselearn.com/240/240ReadCode/240ReadCode.html

I just want to understand where he is getting the numbers he references in the video.

An example of one of the questions provided is as follows

```
Private Sub cmdQuestions5_Click()

Dim intEntry as Integer
intEndtry = 7
Select Case intEntry
  Case 1
   lblBox.Caption = 1 + intEntry
Case 2
   lblBox.Caption = 2 + intEntry
Case 3
   lblBox.Caption = 3 + intEntry
Case 4 to 8
   If intEntry > 7 Then
     lblBox.Caption = 8 + intEntry
   ElseIf intEntry > 6 Then
     lblBox.Caption = 7 + intEntry
   Else
     lblBox.Caption = 6 + intEntry
   End If
Case Else
   lblBox.Caption = 20
End Select
End Sub
```

It is supposed to equal 14 but I have no idea where this number is coming from even after following the video. Any help or further explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the first time ever posting here and I didn't post it correctly. I was editing it as you read. I apologize and have corrected the issue.

Comment: Is that typo intentional in line 3?

Comment: No, it was not. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: There's only one line which gives 14 as a result...  It's not clear what the question is here?

Comment: You have to watch the posted video to even begin to understand. You're not the only one who isn't clear on the question, neither am I. My whole next test is based on the video above and the code is the first "question" which I am assuming is "What is the caption going to be". This is all the teacher has provided. The video and 10 questions containing different scripts and you have to figure out the number. I know this doesn't make much sense. that's my problem too.

Comment: The code you posted is clear, and how it arrives at 14 is also clear, but sorry I can't watch that video.

Comment: to understand why its giving back 14, the most basic ting to do is  to move line by line in the code. https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbadebug2010/debug01.php

Comment: `intEntry` is not equal to 1,2 or 3.  It is however between 4 and 8: it's not greater then 7 but it is greater than 6, so that's your answer right there (7+7).

Comment: @JamieSmith, do you know that the `Select Case` statement does?

Comment: Yes I know the Select Case. I just didn't understand how he arrived at 14 nor how what he was doing in the video translated to actual code. My thought process was if professionals can't understand it then it's not just me. Or that maybe I could be directed to where I could gather more info. Thank you for the info, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Warning***: this seemed easier to explain when I started, and I've been LOL'ing while finishing it up, but instead of throwing it away I might as well post it.  This could confuse you more, or maybe not.  Everyone learns differently.  Sorry if I makes things worse!

---

Important Point:
**The video is not related to the question you posted** and whon't help you solve it.

*My thoughts on the video anyway:*

Note that he calls the video *"The Method **I** Use To Read Code"*.  Everyone learns different ways (and he knows it), especially when it comes to math & logic (in my opinion), and it seems to me that he is acknowledging that, so don't stress too much.

I found the video hard to follow, and the main part I had an issue with is referring to number of "Loops" (in his first column).

- `intH` is counting from 1 to 3.
- each time that `intH` changes, `intQ` counts from 2 to 1. *(Step -1 means counting backwards by 1's.)*

In my head, I think like this:

- the first FOR statement runs: now `intH` = 1.  So this is Loop **#1**
- now the next FOR statement runs starting with `intQ` = 2.  So this is Loop **#1-2**
- then `intQ` decreases by 1. So this is Loop **#1-1**
- Now `intH` will increase by 1, so this is Loop **#2**

and so on..

So in order, *I* would think of the "Loop Position" as:

```
1
1-2
1-1
2
2-2
2-1
3
3-2
3-1
```

Not sure if that makes any more sense.  **It's hard to describe a thinking process in text.**  :-)

A loop inside another loop is called a **nested** loop.

---

### Here's another nested loop of the top of my head...

- I have **5** kids.  *(I actually don't OMG that would suck.)*
- I named them `K1` through `K5`.
- Each time I yell at a kid to get ready for bed, they need to **Brush** and **get into PJ's**.
- **Brush** consists of 2 parts: **Brush Hair** (Part #1) and **Brush Teeth** (Part #2)
- **PJ's** consist of 2 parts: a **top** (shirt) and a **bottom** (pants).
- My kids are *terrible* and don't do anything together, and also don't do anything unless I yell at them (so I have to yell at each of them individually to complete each individual task.)

>

> (**Begin Procedure** *"Get Kids Ready For Bed"*)
>
> (Begin loop 'Kid')
>
> *I yell at `K1`* :  <sub>`Kid=1`</sub>
>
> > `K1` get ready for bed!
> >
> > *(begin sub-loop 'Brush')*
> >
> > `K1` Brush!
> >
> > > `K1` Brush Hair!  <sub>`Brush=1`</sub>
> > >
> > > `K1` Brush Teeth!  <sub>`Brush=2`</sub>
> >
> > *(end sub-loop 'Brush')*
> >
> > *(begin sub-loop 'PJs')*
> >
> > `K1` get into your PJ's!
> >
> > > `K1` get into your PJ Top!  <sub>`PJs=1`</sub>
> > >
> > > `K1` get into your PJ Bottoms!  <sub>`PJs=2`</sub>
> >
> > *(end sub-loop 'PJs')*
> >
> > *(K1 is now ready for bed.)*
>
> **NEXT KID...**
>
> *I yell at `K2`* :  <sub>`Kid=2`</sub>
>
> > `K2` get ready for bed!
> >
> > *(begin sub-loop 'Brush')*
> >
> > `K2` Brush!
> >
> > > `K2` Brush Hair!  <sub>`Brush=1`</sub>
> > >
> > > `K2` Brush Teeth!  <sub>`Brush=2`</sub>
> >
> > *(end sub-loop 'Brush')*
> >
> > *(begin sub-loop 'PJs')*
> >
> > `K2` get into your PJ's!
> >
> > > `K2` get into your PJ Top!  <sub>`PJs=1`</sub>
> > >
> > > `K2` get into your PJ Bottoms!  <sub>`PJs=2`</sub>
> >
> > *(end sub-loop 'PJs')*
> >
> > *(K2 is now ready for bed.)*

*...and so on.*

So how many times did I yell by the time all 5 kids are ready?

Here's the loop:

```
Sub GetKidsReadyForBed()

    Dim Kid As Integer, Brush As Integer, PJs As Integer

    Debug.Print "(Time to get the kids ready for bed.)"

    For Kid = 1 To 5

        Debug.Print "(Prepare to yell at Kid #" & Kid & ")"

        For Brush = 1 To 2
            Debug.Print "YELL @ Kid #" & Kid & " Brush part #" & Brush & "!"
        Next Brush

        For PJs = 1 To 2
            Debug.Print "YELL @ Kid #" & Kid & " Put on PJs part#" & PJs & "!"
        Next PJs

        Debug.Print "(Finished yelling at Kid #" & Kid & ")"

    Next Kid

    Debug.Print "(All Kids are finally ready for bed.)"
End Sub
```

Each kid got yelled at 4 times. 
    (Brush * 2) + (PJs * 2)

I have 5 kids, so number of Yells:
    ( (Brush * 2) + (PJs * 2) ) * 5

so:

```
( 2 + 2 ) * 5
```

so:

```
4 * 5 = 20 yells in total.
```

(If you don't know what Debug.Print is for, ask your teacher why he hasn't told you yet.  It's my main tool for understanding how code works!)

---

**As for the code you posted**, you said you know how `Select..Case` works?  If so, this should be simple:

Stepping through the code line by line:

```
intEndtry = 7
```

> Ok, the value of `intEndtry` is 7.

```
Select Case intEntry
```

> let's select which line to run based on the value of `intEndtry`

```
  Case 1
```

> Does `intEndtry` = 1?  No.  Skip to the next possible case.

```
Case 2
```

> Does `intEndtry` = 2?  No.  Skip to the next possible case.

```
Case 3
```

> Does `intEndtry` = 3?  No.  Skip to the next possible case.

```
Case 4 to 8
```

> Is `intEndtry` between 4 and 8?  **YES**!  Don't skip.

```
   If intEntry > 7 Then
```

> Is `intEndtry` more than 7?  No.  Skip to the Else or elseIf.

```
   ElseIf intEntry > 6 Then
```

> Is `intEndtry` more than 6?  **YES**!  Don't skip.

```
     lblBox.Caption = 7 + intEntry
```

> Make lblBox.Caption = 7 + intEntry
>   so, lblBox.Caption = 7 + 7

```
   Else
```

> this ELSE doens't apply since the previous IF statement criteria matched.
>          End If
>       Case Else
>
> The Select..Case statement's ELSE doesn't apply since we already had a match.

```
End Select
```

> Done.  So that last thing we did was make `lblBox.Caption = 7 + 7`

***Clear as mud?***  :-)

I'd suggest you bring a copy of the page to the teacher to show him that you at least tried your best...  you should get bonus marks for that!

Don't get discouraged, there's definitely a learning curve involved.

**Good luck!**

Comment: Thank you!! This makes a lot more sense now!!

Comment: I only had a minute to respond earlier but I wanted to come back and thank you for all the time you took to explain this and all the detail you put in to your answer. I completely understand now and only missed 2 on my test. I loved the kids example and was cracking up the whole time, especially because I have 5 kids, LOL. It doesn't suck that bad, they all entertain each other for the most part. Once you start adding after kid 3 you don't really even notice.

Comment: You're welcome -- nice job on the test!  I'm a single dad of 1 pubescent boy, which is more than enough.  (He's learning VBA right now too!)